# How to execute CPPUNIT_TEST repeatedly for multiple times in cppunittest?

Tags: cppunit

I am adding some sample code related to cppunittest. In which I want to execute myTest2 CPPUNIT_TEST for multiple times or repeatedly.OR If there are two or more classes which contains some CPPUNIT_TEST , I want to execute one of the registered test "Ex. Test1" for multiple times. How to do that?

```
class Test1: public CppUnit::TestFixture
{
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(Test1);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(myTest11);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(myTest12);
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();

public :
    void myTest11(void)
    {
        cout << "%s"<< __func__ << endl;
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT(add(10, 5));
    }
    void myTest12(void)
    {
        cout << "%s"<< __func__ << endl;
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT(sub(10, 5));
    }
};
CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION(Test1);
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you would want to do that? Each test case runs with a new instance of Test1, so unless you use static variables and/or calls to random() you will always execute the same test.

Comment: Actually, I want to run same CPPUNIT_TEST multiple times. For example power on and off multiple times to check were it is taking/handling inputs correctly or not. I found RepeatedTest class in cppunit_test but I am not getting how to use it. like that if any other way is there??